# Socket programming in python counter not working

Tags: python, sockets

I am making a client and a sever relation ship using python. The client has a button in which I click the button it will connect to the server and count the clicked button by the client.

But in my situation, the server only count once and the client button is not working anymore.
does anybody has an idea about my case? any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

this is my code

client.py

```
import socket 
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()

root.title("ADKOO")
root.geometry("150x80")

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12340
s.connect((host, port))

def counterPlus():
  s.send('sent by '+host)


app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

button1 = Button(app, text="+", width=15, command=counterPlus)

button1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

server.py

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12340
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
pressed = 0
while True:
 c, addr = s.accept()
 pressed = pressed + 1
 print 'Got connection from', addr
 print c.recv(1024), 'pressed count', pressed
 #c.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`server.py` accept a client, then receive only once, and accept another client....

You need loop to continuous receive data from client.

Try following code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12340
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    pressed = 0
    while True:
        print 'Got connection from', addr
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        pressed = pressed + 1
        print data, 'pressed count', pressed
```

**NOTE**

Your code and this code does handle one client at a time.

To handle multiple client, you need multiprocess / multithreading / select / ...

Comment: thanks falsetru for your answer, it works on me... do u have any example for multiprocess?